# Google forms - Dependent field

Tags: google-forms

I'm playing with Google Forms and I'm looking for a way to create a dependent field.
What I mean is a first section with a code and a second section with a options field which values depend on the answer to the code.

Here is a sample: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScpB5sOCdl-MdTzicrebP-EkO0sPFkDELNTKEXhxBUwpRxTnQ/viewform

Is it possible to trigger an event on clic to the next button (the one which allow to go from the first to the second section) ?

Answer (score -1):

No, I'm afraid this is not currently possible unless you use app scripts.

If you would like to use app scripts and haven't used them before, there are some good tutorials by Google Developers [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles).